# Convert time to yesterday after 12am

Tags: swift, date

I would like to convert the time to yesterday after 12AM.
For example: If message sent at 11:35PM and the time now is 12:00AM i would to convert it to yesterday

```
let dateformatter = DateFormatter()
dateformatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.local
dateformatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"

let interval = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: self, to: Date())

if let day = interval.day, day > 0 {
   return day == 1 ? "Yesterday at" + " " + formatter.string(from: date as Date) : dateformatter.string(from: date as Date) 
}
```

This code converting to yesterday 24hrs later from sent time.

Comment: You are doing this the hard way. Look at the `doesRelativeDateFormatting` property of `DateFormatter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**There is a method in Calendar called `isDateInYesterday`**

```
extension Date {
    func isYesterday() -> Bool {
        let calendar = Calendar.current     
        return calendar.isDateInYesterday(self)
    }
}
```